# CSS3 layout with position: absolute pushing down content

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive page where I need to insert various content in different heights:

- The upper part is an image with a gradient overlay (red).
- Beneath it is a div with the same color (blue), so it looks like its a smooth transition between those 2 divs.

[image: Example]

The issue is that the content (yellow) needs to push down the blue div depending on how much content is inside the yellow div, but the yellow div needs to be `position: absolute` to be displayed where it is.

Is this doable in pure CSS? Or would I need javascript to calculate the hight of the blue div?

[Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhj65aam/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="pr">
    <img src="http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/demobilleder/detartistchannel2.jpg">
    <div id="campaignreleases"></div>
    <img id="camlogo" src="http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/css/lyttesession.svgz" alt="MusikDK logo">
</div>
<div id="camrel">
    <img src="http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/demobilleder/detlyttealbum.jpg" alt="ALBUMNAME">
    <p>Below I need to add whatever I'll need. So basically it needs to push down the "camrel" div, but all this content also needs to be positioned just below the logo (inside the "pr" div)</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #ddd
}
.pr {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px
}
.pr img {
    width: 100%
}
#campaignreleases {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.2) 0%, rgba(26, 188, 156, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.2)), color-stop(100%, rgba(26, 188, 156, 1)));
}
#camlogo {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top:15%;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    max-width: 500px
}
#camrel {
    background: #1ABC9C;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
#camrel img {
    width: 250px;
    .roundedcorners;
}
```

Comment: Go'dag Morten, være så venlig at oprette en jsfiddle. Please set up a jsfiddle, so we can see your code. Tak.

Comment: Are the red and blue divs just to put in the background? If so, why not use a CSS background on the body?

Comment: @JezD: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhj65aam/1/

Comment: @misterManSam: Almost right. The blue div needs to be flexible in height as the content inside the yellow div can change height. I'm not sure how using it as css-backgrounds will change the problem?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, but this is what CSS backgrounds are for! Something like [this example](http://jsbin.com/vixege/1/edit)

Comment: @misterManSam: Thanks for your example. Its close to what I want to achieve, but if you look at your JSFiddle, the gradient gets longer and longer the more content you insert and thats the issue. The gradient needs to be persistant over the image. Otherwise very long content would make the gradient almost invisible over the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable with pure CSS, but you need to turn the way it's CSSed around. The red and blue div need to be `position: absolute;` since their height doesn't change, and the yellow div should have `position: relative;` because then that div will set the height of the document.

You might get a problem with the background color that way. But that can be solved by giving the body the same background color as the blue div.

In case it is unclear, or you still have no idea how to do it, let me know. I'd be happy to help.

---

Edit: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhj65aam/3/) using yours, to create what I explained above.

Comment: Thanks! The blue div will change thats the problem. The only "fixed" hight is the red div, but as it shrinks when the screen gets smaller I cant set a fixed height on that. I've updated with a JSFiddle link.

Comment: Sorry couldnt update. Heres the link:  jsfiddle.net/Lhj65aam/1

Comment: Wow that got it close. However I'm not able to make the logo wider as it seems it sets the content to the size of the cover. And if I put it outside the #camlrel it screws it up.

Comment: I've updated it, and used a relative width for the logo. It's 50% of the containing div now. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: YES! Thanks it works just as I hoped I would be able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on your design with a background pseudo element combined with some z-index to get a simple layout. `.content:after` is `position:fixed` to remain attached to the viewport to keep a consistent gradient.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/cokimu/3/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">
        <img id="camlogo" src="image-source" alt="MusikDK logo">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <!-- fill me up! -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: #ddd;
}
.wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
        background: url(http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/demobilleder/detartistchannel2.jpg) center 0 no-repeat;
    height: 600px;
    background-size: 800px;
    z-index: -3;
    position: relative;
}
.content:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(26,188,156,0.2) 0%, rgba(26,188,156,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(26,188,156,0.2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(26,188,156,1)));
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -2;
    left: 50%;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -400px;
}
#camlogo{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    top:10%;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    max-width: 500px
}
.content {
    margin-top: -400px;
    padding: 0 200px;   
}
```